# Cannot add property _children, object is not extensible

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightningtreegrid

I am trying to work with lwc tree-grid and move the results returned from my query display there related data.

However it looks like the return is now non-extensible and as such you can no longer simply do the following to get the data into the '_children' property

```
@wire(fetchTimesheets) timeSheetRate({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        let objs = [];

        for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
            console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data[i])));
            let obj = data[i];
            if(obj['Timesheet_Rates__r']) {
                obj._children = obj[ 'Timesheet_Rates__r' ];
                delete obj.Timesheet_Rates__r;
            }
            console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)));
            objs.push(obj);
        }
        this.gridData = objs;

    } else if (error) {
        console.log('An error has occurred:');
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

Any ideas, The only thing i can think of at this point would be return a class so Apex rather then the objects

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer clone the array first and then work on that array.

```
@wire(fetchTimesheets) timeSheetRate({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
        let objs = [...data];

        objs.forEach(function(obj){
            if(obj['Timesheet_Rates__r']) {
                obj._children = obj[ 'Timesheet_Rates__r' ];
                delete obj.Timesheet_Rates__r;
            }
        });
        this.gridData = objs;
    } else if (error) {
        console.log('An error has occurred:');
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a json parse i was able to pass the data into a new variable and from there i could use a map on my new list do change the values on a new list and put it back into the tracked proporty

```
if (data) {
        let objs = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
        objs.map(e =>{
            if(e[ 'Timesheet_Rates__r' ]){
                e._children = e[ 'Timesheet_Rates__r' ];
            }
        })
        this.gridData = objs;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [reference](https://www.json.org/xml.html#:%7E:text=Extensibility,to%20represent%20data%20in%20it.), JSON is not extensible because it does not need to be. JSON is not a document markup language, so it is not necessary to define new tags or attributes to represent data in it.

So you need to make a copy of the parsed object onto a conventional JS object which supports property extension.